# How to share the created pdf to whatsapp to a particular number? Tryed all the packages it's not working..I can only send text

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to share the created pdf to whatsapp to a particular number?

Tryed all the packages it's not working..I can only send text

Answer (score 0):

You can send those type of messages via the `WhatsApp API`.
Take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media/